# Unknown column '' in 'field list MySQLConnector MySQLException

Tags: list, model-view-controller, mysql-connector

I have a controller class and inside a method of the controller class, I have List Defined as below.

```
List<TrackedStoreProductsViewModel> currTrackProds = _context.Tracked_Products.Select(p => new TrackedStoreProductsViewModel()
        {
            TrackedProducts = p,
            currentPrice = _context.Store_Products.Where(x => trackedId.Contains(x.product_id)).FirstOrDefault(s => s.product_id == p.product_id).Product_Price_History.OrderByDescending(pr => pr.price_timestamp).Select(pr => pr.price).FirstOrDefault(),
            userEmailId = _context.User_Accounts.FirstOrDefault(u => u.account_number == p.account_number).email_id,
            userFirstName = _context.User_Info.FirstOrDefault(u => u.account_number == p.account_number).first_name
        }
         ).ToList();
```

Here I am getting the following exception error

[image]

Here the exception error is 'Unknown column 't.Store_Productsproduct_id' in 'field list'.

I checked all the models related to this, set up a breakup point stepped in still couldn't find where it is defined that way? Can someone suggest me an approach I can possibly follow to fix this issue?